# Style not applied as a variable in SLIM for Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

```
Rails 5.2.3
Ruby 2.6.3
Bootstrap
SLIM
```

In my stylel sheet, I have:

```
.myorg_header {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #3a84ff;
}

.myorg-success-color {
  color: #51d85e;
}


.btn-sq-xs {
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
  }
```

In my view, I have:

```
- myorg_header_text = " My Organization"
- display_date = "2019-10-01"
- status_style = "myorg-success-color"
- myoorg_button =  "btn btn-sq-xs btn-primary"

.col-lg-12
  .row
    .myorg_header
      = "#{myorg_header_text}"
    button *{class: myoorg_button} type="button"
    h4 *{class: status_style}
      = "Some Text"
    = display_date
```

"My Organization" is showing up in blue, and the font size is what's specified in the stylesheet

The button is showing up in green, and size is what's in the style, next to the "My Organization text"

But "Some Text" is showing up next to it, as h4, but the font color is black, not green, and the display_date text is showing up next to it, but its vertical alignment is top of row.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Can you try: `h4 *{class: status_style} = "Some Text"` ?

Comment: I've already tried it, and it does not work